# Joined 3 Tables in SQL and Getting duplicated records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables and trying to get the data out without having many duplicates.  Please check on the image that I sent.  This is the desired result.  Thanks.

I tried:

EDIT:

All this does is Grab all records from Parts then all the records from Assemblies then all the records in Materials.  So the return records is HUGE. Here is the standard SQL Statement that connects these tables together.

```
SELECT impPartID, impShortDescription, uimpConfigPartID as ConfigID, 
imaPartID, immPartID FROM Parts
Left Outer Join PartAssemblies on IMAMETHODID = IMPPARTID and 
IMAPARENTASSEMBLYID = 0
Left Outer Join PartMaterials on IMMMETHODID = IMPPARTID and 
IMMMETHODASSEMBLYID = 0
```

So I tried this

```
Select p.impPartID, p.impShortDescription, p.uimpConfigPartID as ConfigID, 
a.imaPartID as Assem, m.immPartID as Materials
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
 from parts p where uimpConfigPartID <> ''
 ) p full join
 (select a.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
  from assemblies a
 ) a
 on a.IMAMETHODID = p.impPartID and a.seqnum = p.seqnum full join
 (select m.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
  from materials m
 ) m
 on m.IMMMETHODID = coalesce(a.IMAMETHODID, p.impPartID) and
 m.seqnum = coalesce(a.seqnum, p.seqnum)
```

[image: 3 Tables with the desired result]

Comment: Here's a guide how to ask question.  Please read.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`, `union all` and `group by`:

```
select p.partid, a.descassembly, m.descmaterial
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from parts p
     ) p full join
     (select a.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from assemblies a
     ) a
     on a.partid = p.partid and a.seqnum = p.seqnum full join
     (select m.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from materials m
     ) a
     on m.partid = coalesce(a.partid, p.partid) and
        m.seqnum = coalesce(a.seqnum, p.seqnum);
```

Comment: @mrmcg well you have your answer here. This works. Here is the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1cb4772f518102261ac8faa273c017f Gordon, nice!

Comment: Thanks. But this does not work. All this does is Grab all records from Parts then all the records from Assemblies then all the records in Materials.  So the return records is HUGE. Here is the standard SQL Statement that connects these tables together.

SELECT impPartID, impShortDescription, uimpConfigPartID as ConfigID, imaPartID, immPartID FROM Parts
Left Outer Join PartAssemblies on IMAMETHODID = IMPPARTID and IMAPARENTASSEMBLYID = 0
Left Outer Join PartMaterials on IMMMETHODID = IMPPARTID and IMMMETHODASSEMBLYID = 0

Comment: @mmcg . . . Did you run this?  Look at the SQL Fiddle.